# "TypeError: Metaplex is not a constructor" when executed in browser

Tags: metaplex-js

anyone can tell me what happened below:
when I run the following statements with react scripts, it succeeded.

```
...
const { Metaplex } = require('@metaplex-foundation/js');
const { Connection, clusterApiUrl } = require('@solana/web3.js');
...
const connection = new Connection(clusterApiUrl(networkId));
const metaplex = new Metaplex(connection);
```

but when i open the app in browser(chrome), the console says:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Metaplex is not a constructor
```

Does anyone know what happened and how to resolve such error? Thanks.